# Extract emails from multiple shared mailboxes

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a tool in Excel that will extract emails from a particular mailbox.

```vb
Sub GetFromOutlook()
    Dim OutlookApp as Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim Folder as MAPIfolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim objowner As Variant
    Dim i as Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNameSpace = OutlookApp. GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objowner = OutlookNameSpace.CreateRecipient("abc@email.com")
    Objowner.Resolve
    If objowner.Resolved then
        Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objowner, olFolderInbox) 
    End if

    Dim strDateFilter As String: 
    StrDateFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(Range("Date").Value, "dddd h:nn AMPM") & "'" 
    Dim Items As Object: Set Items = Folder.Items.Restrict(strDateFilter) 

    i = 1
    For each OutlookMail in Items

        Range("eMail_subject").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_Sender").offset(i,0).Value =  OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Body

        i = i + i


    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNameSpace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I need to extract emails from four more shared mailboxes (other than abc@email.com).

1. def@email.com
2. Ghi@email.com
3. Jkl@email.com
4. Mnop@email.com

I tried to insert the following lines.

```
Dim Folder2 as MAPIfolder
Dim Folder3 as MAPIfolder
Dim Folder4 as MAPIfolder
Dim Folder5 as MAPIfolder
Dim objownwr2 as Variant
Dim objownwr3 as Variant
Dim objownwr4 as Variant
Dim objownwr5 as Variant

Set objowner2 =  OutlookNameSpace.CreateRecipient("def@email.com")
Objowner2.Resolve '(and so on for all the other shared mailbox)

If objowner2.Resolved then
    Set Folder =  OutlookNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objowner2, olFolderInbox) 
End if
```

And so on. It only gets the emails from abc@email.com.

Comment: `Set Folder2` rather than `Set Folder`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to loop trough your code changing the account?

Comment: @niton Yes sorry, I've changed the folder to folder2 but still encountering error. I am encountering the debug error under

    Dim strDateFilter As String
    strDateFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(Range("Date").Value, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
    Dim Items As Object: Set Items = Folder.Items.Restrict(strDateFilter)

specifically the "Dim Items As Object: Set Items = Folder.Items.Restrict(strDateFilter)"

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, maybe. But I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with only one outlook.application:

```
sub start()
        Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application: Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
        Dim OutlookNameSpace As Namespace: Set OutlookNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        
       call GetFromOutlook("abc@email.com", OutlookNameSpace)
       call GetFromOutlook("def@email.com", OutlookNameSpace)
       call GetFromOutlook("ghi@email.com", OutlookNameSpace )
       call GetFromOutlook("jkl@email.com", OutlookNameSpace )
       call GetFromOutlook("mnop@email.com", OutlookNameSpace )

       Set OutlookNameSpace = Nothing
       Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End sub

Sub GetFromOutlook(mailadress As String, OutlookNameSpace As Namespace)
        Dim Folder as MAPIfolder
        Dim OutlookMail As Variant
        Dim objowner As Variant
        Dim i as Integer
    
        Set objowner = OutlookNameSpace.CreateRecipient(mailadress)
        Objowner.Resolve
        If objowner.Resolved then
        Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objowner, olFolderInbox) 
        End if
    
        Dim strDateFilter As String: 
        StrDateFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(Range("Date").Value, "dd.MM.yyyy h:nn AMPM") & "'" 
        Dim Items As Object: Set Items = Folder.Items.Restrict(strDateFilter) 
    
        i = 1
        For each OutlookMail in Items
    
        Range("eMail_subject").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_Sender").offset(i,0).Value =  OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
    
        i = i + 1
        Next

        Set Folder = Nothing
        Set OutlookNameSpace = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've tried it however it seems that the emails extracted are not within the DateFilter. it also provides a lot of blank rows which accommodate 10k+ rows.

Comment: I thought your code was working (then mine would have too, as I only added the loop).Therefore I did not check the rest of the code, I will have a look

Comment: It is a bad practice to create a new Outlook instance in the method for processing each shared mailbox.

Comment: Thank you so much @Max, greatly appreciate your help and effort

Comment: @jen Appears the question was answered. If there is DateFilter or blank row concern consider posting a new question.

Comment: is this solved with Eugene's answer? My excel is somehow wrcked and what let me test the code...

Comment: I eliminated the "bad practice"; also the date-filter was set incorrect, and the reason for the empty lines was i = i+i instead of i=i+1....I think now we have got it!

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your help. Took me a while to come back here and provide update for some personal issues. Thank you @Max for your help, appreciate it. Thank you Eugene for the patience and guidance. Tool is working well now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code doesn't contain the end of the foreach loop:

```
For each OutlookMail in Items
    
        Range("eMail_subject").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_Sender").offset(i,0).Value =  OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
    
        i = i + i
```

You need to add the `Next` statement to iterate over all items in the collection:

```
For each OutlookMail in Items
    
        Range("eMail_subject").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_Sender").offset(i,0).Value =  OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
    
        i = i + i
Next
```

To cover multiple shared mailboxes you need to call the method for each of them. Just need to introduce a string parameter for the recipient name and use it in the code instead of the hardcoded one.

But don't create a new Outlook Application instance each time you call the methods. Instead, create an instance once and then re-use it every time you call the method. The code may look like that:

```
Dim OutlookApp as Outlook.Application: Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim recpientName as String = "abc@email.com"

   Sub GetFromOutlook(name as string)
        
        Dim OutlookNameSpace As Namespace
        Dim Folder as MAPIfolder
        Dim OutlookMail As Variant
        Dim objowner As Variant
        Dim i as Integer
    
        
        Set OutlookNameSpace = OutlookApp. GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
        Set objowner = OutlookNameSpace.CreateRecipient(name)
        Objowner.Resolve
        If objowner.Resolved then
        Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objowner, olFolderInbox) 
        End if
    
        Dim strDateFilter As String: 
        StrDateFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(Range("Date").Value, "dddd h:nn AMPM") & "'" 
        Dim Items As Object: Set Items = Folder.Items.Restrict(strDateFilter) 
    
        i = 1
        For each OutlookMail in Items
    
        Range("eMail_subject").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_Sender").offset(i,0).Value =  OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").offset(i,0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
    
        i = i + i

        Next 

        Set Folder = Nothing
        Set OutlookNameSpace = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
   End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, sir Eugene. I forgot to input the "Next" in my code here but in my tool it is written there. I appreciate your help and codes, however I apologize for having a limited knowledge to this and not following what you meant by introducing it in a string parameter. I've tried the code you have provided but I am having an error of "Invalid outside procedure" and highlighted the first part "Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application"

Comment: You can leave declarations at the global scope and put initialization in any function prior to calling the `GetFromOutlook` one.

Comment: Thank you so much Eugene!!! It is working fine now! Really appreciate your help

Comment: Great! It makes sense to mark the answer, self-posting is not the best way of saying thank you.